# Flutter: i want to make a row that have two cards with an image and a text like the photo below

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

Flutter: i want to make a row that have two cards with an image and a text like the photo below

```
body: groups.isEmpty
      ? Center(child: Text('No Students'))
      : ListView(
    children: [
      ...groups.map(
            (group) => Card(
            elevation: 7,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/01.jpg'),
              ),
              title: Text(group),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.person),

            )
            ),
      )
    ],
        )
```

[This is The Full Code!](https://www.codepile.net/pile/OBWDxwX4)

[members image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzBXq.png)

Comment: Hi, can you post your code? Show what you have tried to implement so we can help.

Comment: OK i've tried doing it with ListView and ListTile
"
body: groups.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: Text('No Students'))
          : ListView(
        children: [
          ...groups.map(
                (group) => Card(
                elevation: 7,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/01.jpg'),
                  ),
                  title: Text(group),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.person),

                )
                ),
          )
        ],
            )
"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GridView`, set `crossAxisCount` equal to 2, and place `Column` inside `Card`.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 6,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 10.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Card(
                    semanticContainer: true,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/no_image.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Name",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            )),
                      ],
                    )));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I am starting with flutter at the moment. Is it possible to load items into this list view lazy like RecycleView in Android? Thank you.

Comment: list vew lazy ? I guess you mean `ListView` ?